# Keycloak java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

When I'm sending a request to my Java Spring Boot RESTful webservice for the first time after startup I get the RuntimeException with note "Must set 'realm' in config. My configuration looks like those of most tutorials I've seen and I found nothing on the internet about this particular error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

The full exception looks like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:39) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:100) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:75) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:177) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-10.0.2.jar:10.0.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

and my application.properties looks like this:

```
# Keycloak Configuration
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:9990/auth
keycloak.realm=webshop
keycloak.resource=webshop-client
keycloak.public-client=true
```

Maven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With dependency management

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Have you managed this problem?

Comment: @FerdynandKiepski No, sadly I have no idea what I did with this problem. This thread is 3/4 of a year old and I have barely used Keycloak since.

Comment: For me, it was IntelliJ IDEA problem, invalidation of cache and restart IntelliJ helped. If you were not using IntelliJ, then it was application.properties problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by reloading the maven project:
right click on the pom.xml/maven/ and then reload project.